# Running SQL Server Express on Amazon EC2 Windows instance

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, amazon-ec2

I created a Windows Server 2008 Amazon EC2 instance with IIS and SQL Server Express pre-installed (using this AMI http://aws.amazon.com/amis/Microsoft-Windows/4801904273096347). After logging in I fired up SQL Management Studio and attempted to log into the default instance (Database Engine) using Windows Authentication. I was unsuccessful. I get an error message that says the service may not be running...I double checked to ensure that it was indeed running.

Has anyone setup SQL Server Express using an Amazon EC2 instance? Am I better off using a base Windows Server 2008 instance and installing SQL server from scratch? Do I need to create a user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so to get this to work properly I ensured all of the SQL Services were running (via the Services MMC) and then had to use SQL Management Studio to connect to the .\EC2SQLEXPRESS instance. Previously I was trying to use the management studio to connect to the default instance (i.e., the machine name).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the European version of that image and I cannot connect to the sql server either.

There are several images where you can. I think you had better use another ami in stead of installing everything yourself.

I have been able to connect the local sql server from all EC2 instances except for on this ami.

Comment: I ended up getting my connection to work by ensuring all of the SQL services were running (via the Services MMC) and then connecting to .\EC2SQLEXPRESS. Previously I was trying to connect to the SQL instance only using the machine name. Good luck!

Comment: ok, I guess sometimes you have to jump through some hoops of fire to make it work. You should post it as answer and accept it, so it can be useful for others. :)